# Setting value to global variable from a function

Tags: angularjs

I want to assign the global variable `$scope.username`the value of `user.name` in the function, but I get null in the `console.log` on the bottom of the page, what am I doing wrong?

```
angular.module('testCon').controller('UserController', function ($scope, UserService, $location) {
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.theUser = [];
    $scope.username = '';

    UserService.getAll().then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );


    $scope.test = function(){
        $scope.users.forEach(function (user) {
                if(user.id == $scope.id && user.name == $scope.name){
                    $scope.username = user.name;
                    console.log($scope.username);
                }         
        });
    }

    console.log($scope.username);


});
```

Comment: so, if the user.id its the same with $scope.id and if the user.name its $scope.name then $scope.username its user.name, dosent make sense

Comment: That logic was from when I wanted to push objects into an array, but I changed my mind. That was for when it matched with what I got from the view. I need the value from `user.name` globally

Comment: Variables which in this condition `user.id == $scope.id && user.name == $scope.name` $scope.id and $scope.name are undefined. Did you defined them?

Comment: All of the variables are defined, I tried to console log them and they were fine?

Comment: make a plunker, how data looks?

Comment: It's not data dependent I just want to assign the value from user.name to the variable $scope.username?

Comment: Can you please share the logs which are being generated, that will help us narrow down the issue.

Comment: When is `$scope.test()` called? It's surely not called before that `console.log` in your code, so that line should be outputting an empty string.

Comment: Yes, `$scope.test()` should be called once the promise has resolved. Perhaps thats where the issue is.